# What is the keyboard short cut to cycle to a minimized window?

Tags: switching, shortcut-menu, application-switcher

For example, if I have 2 Safari windows open. One is minimized and I have focus on the other one, how do I open the minimized one with out using the mouse?

I found <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> activates the next open window in the frontmost application, which will cycle through the open windows.

How do I get to a window that is minimized?

Comment: how did you add the <kbd>⌘</kbd> ?

Comment: you simply add <kbd></kbd> around whatever unicode character you want to represent as a keyboard button

Comment: ^ but it doesn't work in comments :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may seem complicated, although after you've done it a few times and use it regularly you'll have it down. Depending on if you have other windows minimized you may have to tap the left or right arrow keys on the last step to pull up the window you're wanting un-minimized.

> While holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> tap <kbd>tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>←</kbd>
>   then <kbd>↓</kbd> twice, then press <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> ( keep <kbd>⌘</kbd> pressed the until after you've tapped the initial
>   <kbd>↓</kbd> )

Comment: Crap, I've been using O/S X since the public beta and never could figure that out, very cool, thx!

Comment: One other cool thing is after pressing the down arrow, (when you see the window selections on the screen) you can hit tab to cycle through all currently open applications windows :)

Comment: Well that's unintuitive....I had to do it a handful of time to figure out what it's doing but, yeah, it works!  Coolness...this has bugged me forever.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't enabled minimizing windows to the application icon, you can press control-F3 to move focus to the Dock, and then select the window with the arrow keys and press return.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is also useful but the other one answer lets you continue ⌘ tabbing through apps....thanks though.